# Bootstrap 3: Dropdown menu not working with .js and bootstraps files linked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´ve been reading some questions about this issue. Then I have checked the .js .css and bootstrap files I´m linking to my script to make the dropmenu work but it just doesn´t work.

My nav looks likes this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('homepage') }}">
                    <img id="logo" src="/images/logotipo.png">
                </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Acción #1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Acción #2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Acción #3</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Acción #4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('signup_player') }}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"</span>
                        Sign Up
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('login_route') }}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
                        Login
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

My  looks like this, and I think I have everything that is needed there:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Squash Connection - Homepage </title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

                                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/522ed01_part_1_bootstrap-social_1.css" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/522ed01_part_1_bootstrap-theme_2.css" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/522ed01_part_1_bootstrap-theme.min_3.css" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/522ed01_part_1_bootstrap_4.css" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/522ed01_part_1_bootstrap.min_5.css" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/522ed01_part_1_font-awesome_6.css" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/522ed01_part_1_font-awesome.min_7.css" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/522ed01_part_1_jumbotron_8.css" />

</head>
```

At the end of the script I insert my  tagas to add the .js files.

```
<script src="/js/dd00e43_jquery_1.js"></script>

<script src="/js/dd00e43_bootstrap.min_2.js"></script>

<script src="/js/dd00e43_part_3_bootstrap_1.js"></script>
```

This is how I source my .js, .css and bootstrap files with symfony and twig:

```
Stylesheets compiled with Assetic

    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets 'css/*.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Including Javascripts with Assetic

```
    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts
            'js/jquery.js'
            'js/bootstrap.min.js'
            'js/*.js'
        %}

            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}    
    {% endblock %}
```

For me everything looks right, but I don´t know the reason why when the page is loaded and I click on the dropdown menu, it just doesn´t show the links to other pages.

Does anyone know why this could be happening or if I'm missing something and I'm not noticing?

Thanks.

Comment: reproduce the issue in fiddle

Comment: I tried it also in fiddle @JSantosh and it worked too. But as I told to Quade Dumont maybe I'm doing something wrong when I source my files with symfony.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me when I reproduced it with CDNs in JSBin, link below.(resize view screen to test mobile/desktop versions)

http://jsbin.com/yameludede/edit?html,css,output

I would check where you source jQuery and Bootstrap from. Try the CDNs:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: I tried it this way and it also works for me @QuadeDumont. I'm using Symfony 2.7 and maybe I'm doing something wrong when I source for my .js, .css, and bootstrap files. Because then all the files are sourced but it is not working. I will edit my post and show how I'm doing it with symfony. Thanks for your answer.